# Handling primary and secondary connection strings with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an application which is currently using DbContextPooling. I have been tasked with rotating primary and secondary connection strings. So is there a way of handling this in EF Core?

Comment: You can specify different connection strings in a context's constructor. You can pass a different connection string *name*. What does `primary` and `secondary` mean though and why would you rotate them? If you ask about failover, it doesn't work that way

Comment: Our application is being supplied a primary and secondary connection string and at any time these strings will be rotated. That is, one of them will fail to work and we must failover to the other. We are to read the new connection strings and apply them to our contexts. This must happen seamlessly. I can’t believe this isn’t possible somehow...

Comment: The *correct* way to handle this is via load-balancing/failover at the network level. You proxy through the load balancer or other appliance and it routes to one or the other database server instance. When one goes down, your application doesn't know or care. Requests just get sent to the other instead. One connection string and no issues.

Comment: I'm not sure this possible @ChrisPratt as the connection is to the same database and it's only the connection string (username and password) that'll have changed. I need to change the context to use the new settings.

Comment: Why a different user/pass?

Comment: The primary and secondary strings get rotated every so often.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  It's even easy.  It may be incompatible with DbContextPooling, however.  You'll need to test.

On your DbContext implement OnConfiguring, acquire the correct connection string and use it.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connectionString = ...;
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, with connection pooling, you'll end up with a mixed bag, with some connections to one and some connections to another and an almost random selection of which connection is actually used. This is actually kind of dangerous even without pooling, as there could be outstanding connections to the "bad" instance that will suddenly fail when that goes down.

Comment: "Connection Pooling" is fine.  It's only DbContextPooling that's an issue.  IE your Sql Server connections will be pooled and reused across DbContext instances even without DbContextPooling.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Connection Pooling?

Comment: Sorry. That's what I meant. Context pooling

Comment: @JohnMorsley Sql Client Connection Pooling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling